# QEMU gives error: Device requires 64mb(67108864 bytes), block backend provides 4gb(4437121024 bytes)

Tags: qemu, macos

When I run this:
`qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt,accel=hvf -device ramfb -cpu host -smp 8 -m 8G -device VGA,vgamem_mb=256 -device qemu-xhci -device usb-kbd -device usb-tablet -rtc base=localtime,clock=host -drive id=boot,if=none,file=/Users/brandon/windows.img,format=raw -drive file=windows.iso,format=raw,if=pflash,index=1 -bios ./QEMU_EFI.fd -device nvme,drive=boot,serial=boot -device ich9-intel-hda -device hda-duplex -device virtio-net,netdev=vmnic -netdev user,id=vmnic`, I see an error saying `qemu-system-aarch64: device requires 67108864 bytes, block backend provides 4437121024 bytes`. Previously, I created a drive called windows.img with the size of 64G using `qemu-img create windows.img 64G`. This outputted "Formatting 'windows.img', fmt=raw size=68719476736". I am currently on the latest version of macOS Ventura and the latest version of qemu-8.0. I am running an arm64 machine with an arm64 Windows 11 iso and a 64gb disk image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.